# How to get genymotion in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, genymotion

I want to install Genymotion in Ubuntu 14.04 but I can't seem to find out how. I have followed all the instructions but the problem is that the genymotion.bin file isn't compatible with my system. It says on the website that it's only for Ubuntu 15.10 and above. Does anyone know where I can get a lower version of genymotion? Also I've done all the steps for installation but when I double click the genymotion file nothing happens (but that's probably because it's not compatible for my system). I have also installed the latest version of VirtualBox. I do not want to update my system because when I do it messes up my Chromebook and I am not able to access anything. The screen is just blank and I have a black X as a cursor. I also have no access to the terminal or any of my files. When I look up "download a lower version of Genymotion", Google spits out some results but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Could somebody give a link to genymotion archive for downloading tool ecpecially for ubuntu 14.04? I couldn't find it